# Cocos2d 3 (blur) shaders

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, shader

Here on StackOverflow similar questions for v2 have been posted before. However they all point to tutorials using the older version of cocos2d. And in [those tutorials](http://smashriot.com/cocos2d-v2-0-and-shaders/) the shaderProgram property of a CCNode is used to add a shader, however this property does not exist in Cocos2d 3.

How should I go about it now? My goal is to blur the entire screen (live).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see on cocos2d github, `shaderProgram` property declaration was moved to `CCNode_Private.h` header file.

`#import "CCNode_Private.h"` where you need it should work.

Comment: @user2159978 This answer was posted months ago, cocod2d could have changed many times since then.

Comment: Even in that version it was already marked as deprecated and it wasn't already recommended to use it. So now you get a result - it is partially/totally deleted from cocos2d library. Could provide an answer according to a current version?